# How to find what javascript is acting on a DOM element on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I have red other answers however none of them cover my case.

I have a page (http://www.lacertussoftware.com/) and there is some javascript in one of my included files that is setting the min height and height of my page on the body tag. How can i figure out what javascript is doing this? I have 7 or so files that if i remove my parallax effect / nice scrolling / the gap all go away and don't know what is doing it. Breakpointing is not useful as its on page load (especially because the code i have included on the page is not minified.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply searching the sources for `/min-height/` or `/body.{0,50}min-height/` (and the CSSOM equivalent `minHeight`)?

Alternatively you can add a getter/setters for the `style` property to the HTMLElement/Element prototype which logs accesses to the style property and then forwards calls them to the native browser implementation. If that doesn't work you may also have to instrument `.setAttribute()` since the style property can be modified that way too.
Obviously this has to be done as early as possible in the document.

You could also try chrome's "break on attributes modification" feature in the the elements view of the dev tools. Or the DOMEvent breakpoints under sources.

Comment: I used break on attribute. Thanks.. I don't know how to read the code ive found and what to remove to stop it setting the height. But atleast im looking at the right code

Answer (score 1):

You could try inserting a `debugger;` statement as a first thing in the dom ready handler, all js will pause.
Now right click on the element in the source and add a break on -> attributes modifications